# Drawing elements on a bar chart in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi I trying to create a histogram chart that takes in an array of years and then plots the frequencies of them. Right now this is drawing the axis for the chart but not the actual bars and I am not sure why.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart"></div>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var data1 = [2000, 2001, 2012,2013,2013,2014];
    d3  .select('#chart')
        .datum(data1)
        .call(histogramChart()
            .width(700)
            .height(250)
            .lowerBand(2000)
            .upperBand(2016)
            .bins(17)
            .yAxisLabel("# of Organizations")
            .xAxisLabel("Year")
        );
    function histogramChart(){
        var margin = {
            top: 64,
            right: 32,
            bottom: 72,
            left: 32,
            labels: 32
        };
        //defaults
        var height = 200;
        var width = 500;
        var lowerBand = 2000;
        var upperBand = 2017;
        var bins = 17;
        var chartTitle = ["Selected Partner Organizations Per Year"];
        var yAxisLabel = "y axis label";
        var xAxisLabel = "x axis label";
        var xformat = function(d){return d};
        var formatCount = d3.format(",.0f");
        function chart(selection) {
            var maxBarHeight = height - (margin.top + margin.bottom);
            var chartWidth = width - margin.right - margin.left;
            selection.selectAll('svg').remove();//remove old charts
            selection.each(function(values) {
                var x = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([lowerBand, upperBand])
                    .range([margin.labels, chartWidth]);
                // Generate a histogram using XX bins.
                var data = d3.histogram()
                    .thresholds(x.ticks(bins))
                    (values);
                //fill the chart width, with 1px spacing between
                var numBins = data.length;
                var barWidth = parseInt((chartWidth-margin.labels)/numBins) - 1;
                var y = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.length; })])
                    .range([maxBarHeight, 0]);
                var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
                    .scale(x)
                    .tickFormat(xformat);
                var svgContainer = d3.select(this).append("svg")
                    .attr("class", "chart mini-column-chart")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
                var bar = svgContainer.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter().append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "bar")
                    .attr("x", function(d) { console.log("X" + d.x1);return d.x1; })
                    .attr("y", function(d) { console.log("lenth" + d.length);return d.length; })
                    .attr("width", barWidth)
                    .attr("height", function(d) { console.log(maxBarHeight - d.length );return maxBarHeight - d.length; });
/*
                svg.selectAll("rect")
                    .attr("x", 1)
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                        return "translate(" + x(d.x0) + "," + y(d.length) + ")"; })
                    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0) -1 ; })
                    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.length); });
                */
                console.log("max: " + maxBarHeight);
                var xAxisG = svgContainer.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "x axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate( 0," + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ")")
                    .call(xAxis);
                var header = svgContainer.append("text")
                    .attr("class", "chart-title")
                    .attr("x", width/2)
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .attr("dy", -32)
                    .text(chartTitle);
                bar.append("rect")
                    .attr("x", 1)
                    .attr("width", barWidth)
                    .attr("height", function(d) { return maxBarHeight - d.length; });
                bar.append("text")
                    .attr("class", "axis-label")
                    .attr("dy", "-.75em")
                    .attr("y", 6)
                    .attr("x", barWidth / 2)
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text(function(d) { return formatCount(d.length); });
                xAxisG.append("text")
                    .attr("class", "axis-label")
                    .attr("x", margin.left)
                    .attr("dy", 56)
                    .text(xAxisLabel);
                svgContainer.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "y axis")
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("class", "axis-label")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                    .attr("y", 8)
                    .attr("x", -(height-margin.top-margin.bottom))
                    .style("text-anchor", "start")
                    .text(yAxisLabel);
            });
        }
        chart.title = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return chartTitle;
            chartTitle = _;
            return chart;
        };
        chart.lowerBand = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return lowerBand;
            lowerBand = _;
            return chart;
        };
        chart.upperBand = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return upperBand;
            upperBand = _;
            return chart;
        };
        chart.width = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return width;
            width = _;
            return chart;
        };
        chart.height = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return height;
            height = _;
            return chart;
        };
        chart.bins = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return bins;
            bins = _;
            return chart;
        };
        chart.xformat = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return xformat;
            xformat = _;
            return chart;
        };
        chart.yAxisLabel = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return yAxisLabel;
            yAxisLabel = _;
            return chart;
        };
        chart.xAxisLabel = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return xAxisLabel;
            xAxisLabel = _;
            return chart;
        };
        chart.focusLabel = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return focusLabel;
            focusLabel = _;
            return chart;
        };
        chart.focusValue = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return focusValue;
            focusValue = _;
            return chart;
        };
        return chart;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several errors:

1. `rect` element cannot have content inside it, so this part is wrong

   ```
   bar.append("rect").attr("x", 1)
                           .attr("width", barWidth)
                           .attr("height", function(d) { return maxBarHeight - d.length;  });




    bar.append("text")
           .attr("class", "axis-label")
           .attr("dy", "-.75em")
           .attr("y", 6)
           .attr("x", barWidth / 2)
           .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
           .text(function(d) { return formatCount(d.length); });
   ```
2. Bars actually are drawing, but you specified   `d.x1` for `x` position, which is more than 2000, when I have inspected it, so bars are drawing outside of page (you can inspect it from chrome)

   `.attr("x", function(d) { console.log("X" + d.x1);return d.x1; })`

   instead should be used scales, you have declared earlier ,  so
   `.attr("x", function(d) { console.log("X" + d.x1);return x(d.x1); })`

I have changed  these 2 items , and prepared snippet, which you can run
and continue working from here

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart"></div>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script>
  
    var data1 = [2000, 2001, 2012,2013,2013,2014];
    d3  .select('#chart')
        .datum(data1)
        .call(histogramChart()
            .width(700)
            .height(250)
            .lowerBand(2000)
            .upperBand(2016)
            .bins(17)
            .yAxisLabel("# of Organizations")
            .xAxisLabel("Year")
        );
    function histogramChart(){
        var margin = {
            top: 64,
            right: 32,
            bottom: 72,
            left: 32,
            labels: 32
        };
        //defaults
        var height = 200;
        var width = 500;
        var lowerBand = 2000;
        var upperBand = 2017;
        var bins = 17;
        var chartTitle = ["Selected Partner Organizations Per Year"];
        var yAxisLabel = "y axis label";
        var xAxisLabel = "x axis label";
        var xformat = function(d){return d};
        var formatCount = d3.format(",.0f");
        function chart(selection) {
            var maxBarHeight = height - (margin.top + margin.bottom);
            var chartWidth = width - margin.right - margin.left;
            selection.selectAll('svg').remove();//remove old charts
            selection.each(function(values) {
                var x = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([lowerBand, upperBand])
                    .range([margin.labels, chartWidth]);
                // Generate a histogram using XX bins.
                var data = d3.histogram()
                    .thresholds(x.ticks(bins))
                    (values);
                //fill the chart width, with 1px spacing between
                var numBins = data.length;
                var barWidth = parseInt((chartWidth-margin.labels)/numBins) - 1;
                var y = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.length; })])
                    .range([maxBarHeight, 0]);
                var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
                    .scale(x)
                    .tickFormat(xformat);
                var svgContainer = d3.select(this).append("svg")
                    .attr("class", "chart mini-column-chart")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
                var bar = svgContainer.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter().append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "bar")
                    .attr("x", function(d) { console.log("X" + d.x1);return x(d.x1); })
                    .attr("y", function(d) { console.log("lenth" + d.length);return d.length; })
                .attr('stroke','white')
                    .attr("width", barWidth)
                    .attr("height", function(d) { console.log(maxBarHeight - d.length );return maxBarHeight - d.length; });
/*
                svg.selectAll("rect")
                    .attr("x", 1)
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                        return "translate(" + x(d.x0) + "," + y(d.length) + ")"; })
                    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0) -1 ; })
                    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.length); });
                */
                console.log("max: " + maxBarHeight);
                var xAxisG = svgContainer.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "x axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate( 0," + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ")")
                    .call(xAxis);
                var header = svgContainer.append("text")
                    .attr("class", "chart-title")
                    .attr("x", width/2)
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .attr("dy", -32)
                    .text(chartTitle);
              /*
                bar.append("rect")
                    .attr("x", 1)
                    .attr("width", barWidth)
                    .attr("height", function(d) { return maxBarHeight - d.length; });
                bar.append("text")
                    .attr("class", "axis-label")
                    .attr("dy", "-.75em")
                    .attr("y", 6)
                    .attr("x", barWidth / 2)
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text(function(d) { return formatCount(d.length); });
                    */
                xAxisG.append("text")
                    .attr("class", "axis-label")
                    .attr("x", margin.left)
                    .attr("dy", 56)
                    .text(xAxisLabel);
                svgContainer.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "y axis")
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("class", "axis-label")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                    .attr("y", 8)
                    .attr("x", -(height-margin.top-margin.bottom))
                    .style("text-anchor", "start")
                    .text(yAxisLabel);
            });
        }
        chart.title = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return chartTitle;
            chartTitle = _;
            return chart;
        };
        chart.lowerBand = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return lowerBand;
            lowerBand = _;
            return chart;
        };
        chart.upperBand = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return upperBand;
            upperBand = _;
            return chart;
        };
        chart.width = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return width;
            width = _;
            return chart;
        };
        chart.height = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return height;
            height = _;
            return chart;
        };
        chart.bins = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return bins;
            bins = _;
            return chart;
        };
        chart.xformat = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return xformat;
            xformat = _;
            return chart;
        };
        chart.yAxisLabel = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return yAxisLabel;
            yAxisLabel = _;
            return chart;
        };
        chart.xAxisLabel = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return xAxisLabel;
            xAxisLabel = _;
            return chart;
        };
        chart.focusLabel = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return focusLabel;
            focusLabel = _;
            return chart;
        };
        chart.focusValue = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return focusValue;
            focusValue = _;
            return chart;
        };
        return chart;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```